# Highlight a drop down Menu

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, highlight

Ok, basically I have little idea what I am doing with HTML and CSS.

On my blog: http://oligclimbing.blogspot.co.uk/ I have added a bar along the top linking to different pages on the blog, and to do this I copied a code off a tutorial.

This was the code:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pixopoint.com/wp-content/plugins/pixopoint-menu/scripts/suckerfish_ie.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<ul id="suckerfishnav" class="sf-menu">
  <li><a href="http://oligclimbing.blogspot.co.uk/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://oligclimbing.blogspot.co.uk/p/photos_8.html">Photos</a>
  <li><a
 href="http://oligclimbing.blogspot.co.uk/p/videos.html">Videos
<li><a
 href="http://oligclimbing.blogspot.co.uk/p/about-me.html">BIO
    <ul></ul></a
></li></a
></li></li></ul>
```

When someone hovers over one of the boxes, how do I highlight this fact, e.g the background changes to a slightly darker grey? What would I write?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you just after some CSS like this?

```
#suckerfishnav li:hover { background-color: #eeeeee; }
```

Comment: I guess so, cheers! But where abouts do I put it in the code above?

Comment: In the code above?  No where.  You would add it to your style sheet / css in the head of the document or in an external .css file; the same place you're declaring any styling rules for that "sf-menu" class